# Where can I find an executable created with "shoes" as an example of Ruby GUI windows desktop app

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

Before learning Shoes I want to see some real example of a Ruby GUI windows desktop app using "Shoes". Please point me to some downloadable example for Ruby GUI windows desktop app using "Shoes" library.

Comment: This may end up being closed because it doesn't show or demonstrate what you have done to fail at the task at hand, which is to say finding example  Shoes applications.  However, I have answered, hopefully, your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Shoesrb Site](http://shoesrb.com) where you will find information about the project.

Samples are in the [repository](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/tree/develop/samples).  As far as executables, it is simply Ruby.  Depending on the operating system you are using depends on how you signify an 'executable'.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - the repository